# How to modify JSON values by taking text file content?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I am trying to modify JSON values by taking content from text file but it write the value as the last value of txt file. What I want to do is to write every line from the text file as a value for `item['ax']`. (You can see it in the code.)

```
import json, os

with open('res.json', 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)
    try:
        with open('x.txt', 'r') as file:
            line_x = file.read().splitlines()
            for xv in line_x:
                for item in json_data['resources'][1:]:
                    item['ax'] = xv
    except:
        continue
    os.chdir('../')
    with open('fixed.json', 'w') as out:
        json.dump(json_data, out)
```

Here is a screenshot showing the wrong result:

[image: screenshot showing wrong result]

`449` is the last value in the text file.

Comment: The bare `except:` clause may be hiding a problem. I strongly suggest you avoid doing that and explicitly list the exception(s) that might occur (or at least print or log which one has occurring — i.e. `except Exception as exc:`, then `print(exc)` indented beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this code:

```
for xv in line_x:
    for item in json_data['resources'][1:]:
        item['ax'] = xv
```

You are taking the first line of your text file, assigning to *xv* and then replacing every *item['ax']* throughout the json file with that value. Then you get the next line of the text file and replace all the *item['ax']* in the json file with that new value, and so on, until they all have the value of the last item in the text file.

Perhaps something like this would work better:

```
line_x = file.read().splitlines()
xv = [line for line in line_x]
for item in json_data['resources'][1:]:
    item['ax'] = xv.pop(0)
```